# How to check my network to keep it without problems

Tags: networking, switch

I have 3 networks with 3 different switches. But all the switches have their LED light blinking permanently.

A technician came and told me "Wow, you have very heavy problems with the collisions on your network."

How can I know if this is true? Is it not normal when the LEDs blink constantly? What should I do to keep my network in optimal conditions?

Comment: 3 separate networks or 3 routers on one network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can seriously diagnose network issues by looking at the activity lights. The "technician" was probably trying to sound impressive, but collisions in the context of Ethernet are literally nonexistent when you're using switches and not a problem if you weren't.

Let's get some background on networking. Collisions - a situation in which multiple machines are attempting to send on the same physical wire - can only happen within the collision domain. Back when we used simple hubs (which effectively tie all the wires together), all computers connected to the hub could collide with each other. When that happened, each waited a couple milliseconds and tried again. Thus, collisions were not a problem but an artifact of having several computers on the same wire.

Now we use switches. Every computer connected to a switch is its own collision domain, so there are no collisions. The "send" and "receive" wires are completely separate in full-duplex Ethernet, and there are only two parties on each wire (the switch and the machine or switch it's connected to). One wire per party removes the possibility of collisions.

The activity light on switches just means that some traffic is going through. There's constant light chatter on most networks from [ARP requests](http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/inet-pages/arp.html), service advertisements/broadcasts, [NetBIOS resolution/negotiation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958811.aspx), etc. It is conceivable that unwanted constant activity could be caused by misconfigured switches sending traffic in a loop, but you would notice slowdowns and packet loss if that was going on.

**You're probably fine.** If you need to see what's sending and receiving traffic, I recommend looking at the network utilization statistics on each individual computer (I'm assuming you don't have too many on this network).

Further reading: ["Collision domain" at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain), ["Troubleshooting Ethernet Collisions" from Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/interfaces-modules/port-adapters/12768-eth-collisions.html)

Comment: If you can connect to an administrative interface of the switch (telnet, ssh or web) you can check the status and statistics on each port of the switch. Usually there are collisions, long frames and errors counters on each port that you can use to have some peace of mind.

Comment: Brothers, YOU ARE GREAT!   I mean, Thank you, thank you, thank you. Your knowledge is a ligth. I need to learn more, and refresh the old knowledge. Now i know that i'm in a good place to find answers.                                                                                                              I Really Appreciate your help. Regards.